# Advantage of group functions within an object

Tags: javascript

```
var counter = function(){
    var n = 0;
    return {
        inc: function() {++n},
        reset: function(){n=0}
    }

}

counter.inc() //1,2 and so on\
```

I saw above code somewhere in tutorial for beginner. What's wrong with writing multiple functions? like

```
function reset(){}

function inc(){}
```

Comment: It pollutes the global scope. This way you use a proper design pattern, in this case encapsulation to hide "var n" from global access. It's like having a private member in other OO languages such as C++ or PHP.

Comment: Note: as you've written it, these functions are useless as there is no way to access the counter's value. You probably need a getCount method or something.

Comment: Your example code doesn't work, you need to call `counter()` to create the object.

Comment: @Bergi like this? `var countObj = counter(); counter.inc()` ??

Comment: @EllyChia: no, like `countObj.inc()`.

Comment: @Bergi oh that was typo, sorry

Comment: @EllyChia: Then yes. And the clear advantage over plain functions is that you can create multiple counters by calling the `counter` factory multiple times.

Comment: @Bergi in this pattern do u use the `new()` keyword? There're multiple ways of using `class` in js, i'm confused the use of `new()`.

Comment: @EllyChia: You don't need `new` when the function  `return`s an object, and when you don't need to use prototypes.

Comment: @Bergi I've read few OOP method in JS, and I think I don't have to use them all. for me prototype inheritance is too complicated. in ur exp, what is best? or ur personal preference? I found with revealing module and functional programming is good enough..

Comment: Prototypes allow for efficient sharing of values (e.g. methods) between objects, you definitely should learn about them. You're right, you can do most things without them, though sometimes it might be unidiomatic. If you feel you don't need them, don't use them, but you should know when you need them.

Comment: @Bergi how can I know when I need them when I don't use them?

Comment: @EllyChia: When your code is getting too ugly or too slow or too memory-intensify without them. Which of course is not an exact measure :-)